# CEILING Function - Round to next even number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ceil

How do I make the CEILING function work to automatically assume a cell value is to the nearest even number?

Examples:

If I have a value of 4.25, how do I get it to automatically round to 6?

If I have a value of 6.25, how do I get it to automatically round to 8?

If I have a value of 7.25, how do I get it to automatically round to 8?

If I have a value of 9.25, how do I get it to automatically round to 10?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `=CEILING(A1,2)` for example. As per the help.

Comment: What if the number is 7.25 and I still want it to round to the nearest EVEN number (Ex: 8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CEILING(A1, 2). CEILING rounds the first parameter up to the nearest multiple of the second parameter.

Comment: What if the number is 7.25 and I still want it to round to the nearest EVEN number (Ex: 8)?

Comment: @Bryan M - Have you tried that to see what happens?

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for helping me out with that!  I wasn't understanding how the 2 would work but now I see!  Thank you again for you help

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative to CEILING using a little math and ROUNDUP.

```
=ROUNDUP(A1/2, 0)*2
```

It may be important to note how CEILING works with negative numbers. CEILING always rounds to the numerically larger number.

For the following examples, assume *3* in A1 and *-3* in A2.

```
=CEILING(A1, 2)         'rounds up to +4
=CEILING(A2, 2)         'rounds up to -2
```

On the other hand, ROUNDUP always rounds away from zero.

```
=ROUNDUP(A1/2, 0)*2      'rounds up to +4
=ROUNDUP(A2/2, 0)*2      'rounds away from zero to -4
```

Conversely, ROUNDDOWN and FLOOR (the inverse of ROUNDUP and CEILING) operate in the same manner by in the opposite 'direction'.

Comment: If you can corral 10 mathematicians into a room and ask them whether minus 2 or minus 4 is 'greater than' minus 3, you will likely get 10 different opinions so it's nice to have both options.

Comment: That's about as challenging as herding cats... :)